# Check get parameter in URL by .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, get

I have a website in Wordpress.

If I go to the site with URL:

```
mydomain.com/page/<any_number>/?page=<any_number>
```

then I want to be redirect to home page.

For example if I go at URL:

```
mydomain.com/page/10/?page=38
```

then I want to be redirect to:

```
mydomain.com
```

Can I do it in .htaccess?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: What is the rule then? Everytime somebody hits a link on your website gets redirected to home? _allways_? What if the user clicks a link on your site? Or only when the user hits it from "outside"? Or is it all about cosmetics and you don't want it to be written in the address bar?